# try-state runtime-level hook

Tags: try-runtime

We've been trying to use the new `try_state` hook. However, a significant limitation seems to be that this hook is only accessible from the individual pallets. We want to add some checks that depend on different pallets. Is it possible somehow implement a top-level hook, similar to how it's possible to define `on_runtime_upgrade` hooks on the top-level `Executive` type?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible. The `Executive` only accepts a runtime-wide `OnRuntimeUpgrade` which can be used adjacent to the pallets `on_runtime_upgrade` hooks.
`TryState` can currently only be used on a per-pallet level. But it is a good idea to extend it for runtime-wide usage ([issue](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/13061)).

As makeshift you can maybe write a pallet which only contains the `TryState` logic, but that would be quite ugly.